# How can I tell MATLAB that 'ne' is a variable name and should not be treated as the ne function?

Tags: matlab

I have a huge bunch of data where `ne` is a variable. When I load it into MATLAB 2013b, and try to use it, I get

> Error using ne.
>   Not enough input arguments.

Changing all the `ne` to some other name would be laborious. Any hacks?

This is a short code snippet:

```
function test(lambda, range)
% lambda is a number, range is a vector passed like 1:10 %

    for i = range
        load ('data.mat');    % data.mat contains a variable called 'ne' among others. %
        T = exp(-ne);

    ...
```

When calling the function, there's the error saying that ne has not been provided with enough input args.

Comment: No, my variable is just named 'ne' in a mat file. The mat files have other vars too.

Comment: It's in a function. It is loaded, because I see it when I type whos.

Comment: This means you loaded it inside the workspace but not inside the function. That's why the variabe `ne` is not visible. You could load it inside the function or pass it as an argument.

Comment: Yup, I load the mat file within the function. Like so: function X; load('data.mat'); %this loads the mat file with a bunch of vars%; T = exp(-ne);

Comment: Oh, I typed whos in debug mode.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (better?) way is to avoid loading 'data.mat' directly into the global workspace. If you write:

```
testData = load('data.mat');
```

then your variable will be `testData.ne`, which does not clash with the built-in `ne`. This technique also avoids accidentally overwriting variables in your workspace which happen to have the same name as a variable in the .mat file.

Comment: That's a cleaner way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell matlab `ne` is a variable BEFORE you load it:

```
ne = []; % this will tell matlab ne is a variable
for ii = range
     load('data.mat'); % loading ne
     T = exp(-ne); % should work just fine now...
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: @user2354033 - glad I could help. If this solution worked for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.